# Instance implementation for in a class nested data type

Tags: haskell

I'd like to know how `instance Show` could be implemented for `Gmap` data type presented in following code snippet [Type families](https://wiki.haskell.org/Type_families#The_class_declaration) article without usage of `deriving Show`.

```
class GMapKey k where
  data GMap k :: * -> *
  empty       :: GMap k v
  lookup      :: k -> GMap k v -> Maybe v
  insert      :: k -> v -> GMap k v -> GMap k v

instance GMapKey Int where
  data GMap Int v        = GMapInt (Data.IntMap.IntMap v)
  empty                  = GMapInt Data.IntMap.empty
  lookup k   (GMapInt m) = Data.IntMap.lookup k m
  insert k v (GMapInt m) = GMapInt (Data.IntMap.insert k v m)
```

For this initiating implementation:

```
instance Show (GMap k v) where                                                                                                                                      
  show (GMapInt _) = undefined
```

compiler throws:

```
* Couldn't match type `k' with `Int'
  `k' is a rigid type variable bound by
    the instance declaration
    at /home/x/src/GMapAssoc.hs:27:10
  Expected type: GMap k v
    Actual type: GMap Int v
* In the pattern: GMapInt _
  In an equation for `show': show (GMapInt _) = undefined
  In the instance declaration for `Show (GMap k v)'
* Relevant bindings include
    show :: GMap k v -> String
```

Aside from the main question, I'd like to understand why compiler does not complain in this case:

```
instance Show (GMap k v) where                                                                                                                                      
  show _ = undefined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pattern match on a data constructor of a data family like `GMap` without already knowing it's key type -- i.e. it's not like a GADT, because it's open, so it would be impossible to cover all cases.  So if you want to implement a generic show, you need to do it without accessing the representation directly.  I have two alternatives for you:

### Catch-all instance

After playing around a little, the simplest way I could come up with was to add a method to the class for use in the instance.

```
class GMapKey k where
  data GMap k :: * -> *
  empty       :: GMap k v
  lookup      :: k -> GMap k v -> Maybe v
  insert      :: k -> v -> GMap k v -> GMap k v
  showGMap    :: (Show v) => GMap k v -> String
```

Then you can make a single general catch-all instance.

```
instance (GMapKey k, Show v) => Show (GMap k v) where
  show = showGMap
```

This is a little less smooth than I would desire, but it's not too awfully bad.  My main lament with this method is that it precludes `deriving Show` on the instances, i.e.

```
instance GMapKey Int where
  data GMap Int v        = GMapInt (Data.IntMap.IntMap v)
      deriving (Show)
  ...
```

is illegal because it overlaps with our catch-all instance. This could be kind of a pain if the type gets complex.  The next method does not suffer from this problem.

Anyway, now we have an instance and can use it like usual.

```
example :: (GMapKey k, Show v) => GMap k v -> String
example gmap = show gmap
```

### Dictionary method

If you need to use `deriving Show`, you could do it a more modern way using the [`constraints`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/constraints) package.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables, TypeApplications #-}
import Data.Constraint
```

It also involves adding a method, but instead of returning a `String`, it returns a whole `Show` dictionary.

```
class GMapKey k where
  data GMap k :: * -> *
  empty       :: GMap k v
  lookup      :: k -> GMap k v -> Maybe v
  insert      :: k -> v -> GMap k v -> GMap k v
  showGMap    :: (Show v) => Dict (Show (GMap k v))
```

You can instantiate with `deriving`, and the `showGMap` instance is always the same.

```
 instance GMapKey Int where
   data GMap Int v        = GMapInt (Data.IntMap.IntMap v)
       deriving (Show)
   ...
   showGMap = Dict
```

(You could even use [`DefaultSignatures`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.2.1/docs/html/users_guide/type-class-extensions.html#class-default-signatures) to avoid having to mention `showGMap` in the instances at all!)

Unfortunately, a catch-all instance will still overlap with this, and so we won't have a global `Show` instance for `GMap`s.  However, we can manufacture one locally wherever we need it, using [`withDict`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/constraints-0.10/docs/Data-Constraint.html#v:withDict)

```
example :: forall k v. (GMapKey k, Show v) => GMap k v -> String
example gmap = withDict @k @v (show gmap)
```

which is annoying in a different way.  Fortunately we only need to do this when we need a *generic* `Show (GMap k v)` instance -- if we already know what `k` is then the specific `Show` instances we derived will work.

Maybe there's a way to get the best of both worlds?

Answer (score 1):

The `GMapInt` constructor is specific to, well, `GMap Int`, so you can't use it to construct/deconstruct `GMap k` for `k` other than `Int`.

You probably want this instance:

```
instance Show (GMap Int v) where                                                                                                                                      
  show (GMapInt _) = undefined
```

or, if `Int` is the *only* key type whose maps you whish to be showable (which I'd find strange),

```
instance (k ~ Int) => Show (GMap k v) where                                                                                                                                      
  show (GMapInt _) = undefined
```

The latter has the advantage that the type checker doesn't need to know that the keys are `Int` before resolving e.g. `show empty` (which wouldn't compile in the first approach without an explicit type signature), it instead can utilise the knowledge that the key type *must always* be `Int`. Often useful, though probably not the right thing in your application.

Comment: `instance Show (GMap Int v) where`  I tried also, but ghc 8.0.2 throws exception `Illegal instance declaration for `Show (GMap Int v)`

Comment: It also also say what needs to be done for it to work.

Comment: With your advice I implemented it as follow
 `instance (k ~ Int, Show v) => Show (GMap k v) where
  show (GMapInt k) = "GMapInt (" ++ (show k) ++ ")"`
 but I want to implement a general `instance Show GMap` without restriction to `Int` only.